# distance euclidean in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply, distance

I am trying to compute the distance between a list of coordinates and one coordinate named **cord**.

The expected result is a list with all distance between the i-th element of the list of coordinates and the cord.

## Example:

I have a DataFrame **df** which has a column **Geo_Shape** with a list of list.
And I need to compute a list with distance of all elements of this list with cord.

| Geo_Shape | Name |
| --- | --- |
| [ [1.2,2.3], [0.3,1.7] , [3.2,9.1] ] | try |

cord = [1.2,5.3]

## Code

I try do run this code

```
df['Geo_Shape'].apply(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x - [cord]*len(x), axis=1))
```

But i have this errors:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Someone know howto fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `x` of `numpy.linalg.norm` into `numpy.ndarray`:

```
df['Geo_Shape'].apply(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(np.array(x) - cord, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    [3.0, 3.7107950630558943, 4.294182110716777]
Name: Geo_Shape, dtype: object
```

Comment: when i try to run your code i have an error : 
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

when i try:

```
df['Geo_Shape'].apply(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(np.array(x) - cord, axis=1))
```

i have this errors:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'
```

so i try this:

```
df['Geo_Shape'].apply(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(np.array(x) - np.array([cord]*len(x)), axis=1))
```

And still the same error!

Do you knows what's wrong?